# Rotate angle to target angle via shortest side

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, angle

Hi and thanks for reading.

---

I need to change this void I wrote so that it can work with negative angles.

The goal of this function is to rotate an ANGLE towards the DIRECTION by adding INCREMENT to either clockwise or counterclockwise (+ or -).

However the problem as I said is that it does not work with numbers less than 0 or greater than 360 (2pi). I need to be able to use negative angles as well.

I tried several stuff but couldn't get it to work for a while. Can anyone lend me a hand? I'll be grateful. :D

---

```
public void ToDirection(float Increment, float Direction)
{
    if (CurrentAngle != Direction)
    {
        float ClockwiseDifference;
        float CounterClockwiseDifference;
        //Clockwise
        if (Direction < CurrentAngle)
        {
            ClockwiseDifference = CurrentAngle - Direction;
        }
        else
        {
            ClockwiseDifference = Constants.Rotation_360 - (Direction - CurrentAngle);
        }
        //CounterClockwise
        if (Direction > CurrentAngle)
        {
            CounterClockwiseDifference = Direction - CurrentAngle;
        }
        else
        {
            CounterClockwiseDifference = Constants.Rotation_360 - (CurrentAngle - Direction);
        }
        float CurrentFaceSpeed = Increment;
        if (ClockwiseDifference == CounterClockwiseDifference)
        {
            if (Globals.Randomizer.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            {
                if (ClockwiseDifference < CurrentFaceSpeed)
                {
                    CurrentAngle = Direction;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentAngle -= CurrentFaceSpeed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (CounterClockwiseDifference < CurrentFaceSpeed)
                {
                    CurrentAngle = Direction;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentAngle += CurrentFaceSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (ClockwiseDifference < CounterClockwiseDifference)
        {
            if (ClockwiseDifference < CurrentFaceSpeed)
            {
                CurrentAngle = Direction;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentAngle -= CurrentFaceSpeed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (CounterClockwiseDifference < CurrentFaceSpeed)
            {
                CurrentAngle = Direction;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentAngle += CurrentFaceSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
    if (CurrentAngle >= Constants.Rotation_360)
    {
        CurrentAngle -= Constants.Rotation_360;
    }
    else if (CurrentAngle < 0)
    {
        CurrentAngle += Constants.Rotation_360;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, you can add or subtract 360 until your angle lays in [0-360] interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply unwrap the angle. Then you'll always have angles from 0 to 360. Unwrap the starting angle and the target angle, then perform your turn. Here's a working example (the only method you really need is `UnwrapAngle()`).

```
internal class Program {

    private static object UnwrapAngle(double angle) {
        if (angle >= 0) {
            var tempAngle = angle % 360;
            return tempAngle == 360 ? 0 : tempAngle;
        }
        else
            return 360 - (-1 * angle) % 360;
    }

    private static void TestUnwrap(double angle, double expected) {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} unwrapped = {1}, expected {2}", angle, UnwrapAngle(angle), expected));
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        TestUnwrap(0, 0);
        TestUnwrap(360, 0);
        TestUnwrap(180, 180);
        TestUnwrap(360 + 180, 180);
        TestUnwrap(-270, 90);
        TestUnwrap(-270 - 720, 90);
        TestUnwrap(-725, 355);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer seems to cover the topic quite well:
[Work out whether to turn clockwise or anticlockwise from two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613616/work-out-whether-to-turn-clockwise-or-anticlockwise-from-two-angles?rq=1)

RE: angles that are less than 0 or greater than 360.  Basically, -10 is the same as 350.  720 is the same as 360.  So if you translate the incoming angle so that it lies between 0 and 360, all your problems are solved (presuming your code works for values between 0 & 360 as you suggest).

This is something I've done myself (in a different language before):

```
var wantDir;
var currDir;
var directiondiff;
var maxTurn;

// want - this is your target direction \\
wantDir = argument0;

// max turn - this is the max number of degrees to turn \\
maxTurn = argument1;

// current - this is your current direction \\
currDir = direction;

if (wantDir >= (currDir + 180))
{
    currDir += 360;
}
else
{
    if (wantDir < (currDir - 180))
    {
        wantDir += 360;
    }
}

directiondiff = wantDir - currDir;

if (directiondiff < -maxTurn)
{
    directiondiff = -maxTurn
}

if (directiondiff > maxTurn)
{
    directiondiff = maxTurn
}

// return the resultant directional change \\
return directiondiff
```